# Get schema list mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

As far as I know there are a few ways of getting a list of database names from MySQL into an array in php:

```
//connect to database
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($link, DB_PRESENTATION_LAYER);

//1
$query = "SHOW DATABASES";
$databases = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$databases = mysqli_fetch_row($databases);

//2
$query = "SELECT `SCHEMA_NAME` FROM 'information_schema.SCHEMATA'";
$databases = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$databases = mysqli_fetch_row($databases);

//3 ( DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.4.0 )
$databases = mysql_list_dbs($link);

var_dump($databases);
```

When I do any of the above all i get returned is:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'information_schema' (length=18)
```

Why is this?
Also, why did php not update the mysql_list_dbs() function to work with mysqli?

***CONCLUSION***

For anyone else trying to get databases list this is my function (hopefully i can salvage some usefulness from this question).

Substitute 'database' for the prefix of the database(s) you want returned or just remove it to get all of them.

```
public function get_database_list() {

    $databases = array();

    $query = "SELECT `schema_name` FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name LIKE 'database%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($this -> link1, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($databases, $row['schema_name']);
    }

    return $databases;

}
```

Comment: `fetch_row` returns a SINGLE row of data from the results. You need to fetch in a loop to get ALL of the rows.

Comment: Awwh... now i feel silly, cheers chaps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're fetching only the first row of results, and usually the first database is exactly `information schema`. To list all of them, try this:

```
$list = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($databases)) {
    $list[] = $row;
}
print_r($list);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you should do is:

```
//connect to database
$link = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
mysqli_select_db($link, DB_PRESENTATION_LAYER);

//1
$query = "SHOW DATABASES";
$databases = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$arr = array();
while (($database = mysqli_fetch_row($databases))!=null)
{
    $arr[] = $database;
}
var_dump($databases);
```

Comment: I am trying to get list of all databases but it is returning only one schema "information_schema", why not all databases? Please help.

Comment: Does the `mysql` user you are connecting as have permissions to use other schemas? Can you try it throught `mysql` command line?

Comment: if i get list by PDO then its working. Now i have change the logic, and using PDO. Working as expected..